# possible combinations of an 8 character password

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to calculate the possible combinations for 8 character passwords under specific rules. The password must contain 2 of each of the following: lower case letters, upper case letters, digits, and special characters).

I have 78 ascii characters (lower case letters, upper case letters, digits, and special characters).

lower case letters = 26
upper case letters = 26
digits = 10
special characters = 16

How would I go about calculating the possible combinations under these conditions?

(Additionally, the order in which the characters occur is not important.)

Comment: Are you sure the order of the characters in a password is unimportant?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all ? Do you have any idea of permutations and combinations ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure the order isn't important,  and as for trying to compute it myself. I have attempted that as well but I'm almost certain I am wrong. I've come to 2.0017742e+12 (2001774200000), 4.0035485e+12 (4003548500000), or 1.141762e+14 (114176200000000). Seeing as there is such a large difference between these numbers, I assume I'm way off target. I also don't know what I'm doing in the slightest here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is said that $2$ elements will be selected from each groups so we can do it by $C(26,2) \times C(26,2) \times C(16,2) \times C(10,2)$.Now we have $2$ digits , $2$ lower letters , $2$ upper letter , $2$ special character.

Lets show them with capital letter such that $D-D-U-U-L-L-S-S$ , we can arrange them by $\frac {8!}{2! \times 2! \times 2! \times 2! }$

Hence , our password can be formed by $C(26,2) \times C(26,2) \times C(16,2) \times C(10,2) \times \frac {8!}{2! \times 2! \times 2! \times 2! } $